# Format a string that has extra curly braces in it

Tags: python, escaping, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a LaTeX file I want to read in with Python 3 and format a value into the resultant string. Something like:

```
...
\textbf{REPLACE VALUE HERE}
...
```

But I have not been able to figure out how to do this since the new way of doing string formatting uses `{val}` notation and since it is a LaTeX document, there are tons of extra `{}` characters.

I've tried something like:

```
'\textbf{This and that} plus \textbf{{val}}'.format(val='6')
```

but I get

```
KeyError: 'This and that'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Method 1, which is what I'd actually do: use a [string.Template](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#template-strings) instead.

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> Template(r'\textbf{This and that} plus \textbf{$val}').substitute(val='6')
'\\textbf{This and that} plus \\textbf{6}'
```

Method 2: add extra braces.  Could do this using a regexp.

```
>>> r'\textbf{This and that} plus \textbf{val}'.format(val='6')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'This and that'
>>> r'\textbf{{This and that}} plus \textbf{{{val}}}'.format(val='6')
'\\textbf{This and that} plus \\textbf{6}'
```

(possible) Method 3: use a custom string.Formatter.  I haven't had cause to do this myself so I don't know enough of the details to be helpful.

Comment: Any clue whether string.Template will be deprecated in the future? The new python 3 {} formatting seems to include this. For LaTeX editting however templates are much more convenient.

Comment: @levesque: Well, it hasn't been deprecated as of (pending) 3.4, and it offers different functionality than `{}` formatting itself, so I think that it's going to stick around a while.

Comment: Possibly nicer way to add extra braces rather than using a regex is with `str.translate`. `unformatter = str.maketrans({'{': '{{', '}': '}}'})`, then to fix a given string, `goodstring = badstring.translate(unformatter)` (Note: The question is about Python 3.x; on 2.x, this would only work with `unicode`, not `str`, because only `unicode` supports 1-n translation mappings.)