# Python standard function to escape string before .format()?

Tags: python, string

I want to compose and return Python template string like `"Hey {where}, {who}!"` to use `.format()` from pieces, like

```
template = greeting_template + ", " + appeal_template + some_text
return template
```

But `some_text` is a variable which comes to my function from outer scope, so I don't know if there are any special characters. Special characters for `.format()` are `{` and `}`.

Of course, I can just do

```
some_text = some_text.replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}")
```

and then use `some_text` in template as I like. But I find it a bad solution, for it does not take into account possible extensions of formatting syntax in further versions of Python.

So, is there any standard function (or other way, like `json.dumps` used to escape strings for JavaScript) to escape string before using `.format()`?

Comment: I don't get what is your problem.
Can you post your code with the bad solution ?

Comment: Maybe you should **reconsider** incorporating `some_text` into the template. Ideally a template should have a placeholder for that `some_text` also and render it at the end where it is no longer considered a template.

Comment: I would not worry about supporting something that may never happen. Regardless even if  something were to it would not be anything related to escaping the braces in a string bar they wanted to break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

```
some_text = '{brackets}'
```

1. The OP's method

`some_text = some_text.replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}")`

2. Regular expressions
3. From Shadowranger on [Format a string that has extra curly braces in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161355/format-a-string-that-has-extra-curly-braces-in-it) (**Python 3.x only**)

`unformatter = str.maketrans({'{': '{{', '}': '}}'})`

`some_text = some_text.translate(unformatter)`

Result: `{{brackets}}`

---

Not sure how to preempt these "possible extensions of formatting syntax in further versions of Python", so for now it seems escaping [curly brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_brackets) is your only concern.

Comment: How is that going to escape  anything?

Comment: Ah my bad, thought they had to go. `re.escape(some_text)` would make more sense then.

Comment: @Hevlastka, and that has to do with escaping braces how exactly?

Comment: They want to escape any preexisting `{ }` so when format is called python does not complain about too few arguments or having only one { or } etc.. in the string to avoid errors like `unexpected '{' in field name`

Comment: Right, thanks. If curly braces are the main concern the OP's solution seems fine, otherwise I'm not sure what's expected. MWE in which this would not work?

Comment: That would give you lots of \ when you print the string, run the OP's code on a string with a single { and then run yours. Escaping just the `{` with `{{` would mean you see nothing but one `{` in the output

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that. Seems like the OP's code is pretty good then (or these alternatives). Not sure how to preempt these "possible extensions of formatting syntax in further versions of Python". Thanks for your pointers, hope this is closer to the mark.

Comment: Yep  that would work, their code is doing what they want and bar we could see into the future  it is almost impossible to give a much better alternative.

Answer (score -2):

You can construct template with custom .format() that handles duplicating curly brackets:

E.g.

```
import string

class FormatterWithEscapedCurlyBrackets(string.Formatter):
    def convert_field(self, value, conversion):
        if conversion == 'e':
            return value.replace('{', '{{').replace('}', '}}')
        else:
            return super(FormatterWithEscapedCurlyBrackets, self).convert_field(value, conversion)

fmt = FormatterWithEscapedCurlyBrackets().format

template = fmt("{greeting}, {appeal}{some_text!e}", greeting="Hey {where}", appeal="{who}", some_text="!{brackets}")

template.format(where="here", who="you")
# or
fmt(template, where="here", who="you")
```

Comment: I understood the problem originally totally wrong. Here is another try with custom formatter.